# Selective Cache clearing across load balanced servers (ASP.Net)

Tags: .net, asp.net, architecture, caching, load-balancing

We have a website that runs on two load balanced servers.  We use the ASP.Net caching to help improve performance by caching high usage data.  BUT, occasionally that data changes.  When it does, we need to clear the relevant cache items on BOTH the load balanced servers.  Does anyone have some easy to implement suggestions for how this can be done?

I know that there is software out there to manage this for you (Microsoft Velocity for one).  I also know that there are other options for having separate state servers etc.  However, for what we want they all seem like overkill.  Just a simple mechanism for clearing out specific cache items across servers is all we need for now.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm glad my solution will work for you. If you run into any snags let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a simple web service approach. Our cache clear mechanism checks a web config setting to see if any other servers exist and calls the web service on those server(s) asynchronously.

We store data with specific naming convetions to make it easy to clear what we want. So we pass in either a prefix or postfix for the item to be removed as sometimes it might be user specific (ex. the userid is appended to the name of the item) or application specific (ex. the prefix of the item is the application name).

Here is a VB example of the ClearItem routine that would be called on either one of your nodes:

```
Public Shared Sub ClearItem(ByVal strPrefix As String, ByVal strPostfix As String)

    If WebConfig.Caching_Enabled() Then

        ' Exit if no criteria specified '
        If IsNothing(strPrefix) AndAlso IsNothing(strPostfix) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' At the very least we need a Postfix '
        If Not IsNothing(strPostfix) AndAlso Not strPostfix.Length.Equals(0) Then
            _ClearItem(strPrefix, strPostfix)
        End If

        If WebConfig.Caching_WebFarmEnabled() Then
            ' Now clear the cache across the rest of the server farm '
            _ClearItem_WebFarm(strPrefix, strPostfix)
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Sub _ClearItem_WebFarm(ByVal strPrefix As String, ByVal strPostfix As String)

    If WebConfig.Caching_WebFarmEnabled() Then

        ' Use a web service on each server in the farm to clear the '
        ' requested item from the Cache '

        ' Determine which servers need to remove cache items '
        Dim arrServers As String()
        arrServers = Split(WebConfig.Caching_WebFarmServers(), "|")

        Dim strServer As String ' Holds which server we are currently contacting ' 

        ' Loop through all the servers and call their web services '
        For Each strServer In arrServers

            Dim WS As New WebServiceAsyncCall
            WS.StartCallBack(strServer, strPrefix, strPostfix)

        Next

    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Sub _ClearItem(ByVal strPrefix As String, ByVal strPostfix As String)

    If WebConfig.Caching_Enabled() Then

        ' Determine how we are comparing keys '
        Dim blnPrefix, blnPostfix As Boolean

        If strPrefix.Length.Equals(0) Then
            blnPrefix = False
        Else
            blnPrefix = True
        End If

        If strPostfix.Length.Equals(0) Then
            blnPostfix = False
        Else
            blnPostfix = True
        End If

        ' Reference the Cache collection '
        Dim objCache As System.Web.Caching.Cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache

        ' Exit if the cache is empty '
        If objCache.Count.Equals(0) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Clear out the cache for all items matching the input(s) (on this local server) '
        Dim objCacheEnum As IEnumerator = objCache.GetEnumerator()
        Dim objCacheItem As Object
        Dim objCurrentKey As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
        Dim strCurrentKey As String

        ' Enumerate through the cache '
        While objCacheEnum.MoveNext()

            objCurrentKey = CType(objCacheEnum.Current, DictionaryEntry)
            strCurrentKey = objCurrentKey.Key.ToString()

            ' How are we comparing the key? '
            If blnPrefix AndAlso Not (blnPostfix) Then ' Only by PREFIX '

                If strCurrentKey.StartsWith(strPrefix) Then
                    ' Remove it from the cache '
                    objCacheItem = objCache.Remove(strCurrentKey) ' Returns a reference to the item '
                    objCacheItem = Nothing ' Need to explicitly nuke this because the objCache.Remove() above doesn t destroy '
                End If

            ElseIf Not (blnPrefix) AndAlso blnPostfix Then ' Only by POSTFIX '

                If strCurrentKey.EndsWith(strPostfix) Then
                    ' Remove it from the cache '
                    objCacheItem = objCache.Remove(strCurrentKey) ' Returns a reference to the item '
                    objCacheItem = Nothing ' Need to explicitly nuke this because the objCache.Remove() above doesn t destroy '
                End If

            ElseIf blnPrefix AndAlso blnPostfix Then ' By both PREFIX and POSTFIX'

                If strCurrentKey.StartsWith(strPrefix) AndAlso strCurrentKey.EndsWith(strPostfix) Then
                    ' Remove it from the cache '
                    objCacheItem = objCache.Remove(strCurrentKey) ' Returns a reference to the item '
                    objCacheItem = Nothing ' Need to explicitly nuke this because the objCache.Remove() above doesn t destroy '
                End If

            Else
                ' Not comparing prefix OR postfix? Why bother continuing then! '
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End While

    End If

End Sub
```

You can see that the code above calls other server(s) by using this helper class:

```
Private Class WebServiceAsyncCall

    Public Sub StartCallBack(ByVal strService As String, ByVal strPrefix As String, ByVal strPostfix As String)

        ActiveWebServiceCounter += 1

        Dim clearCacheProxy As New CacheClearService.CacheClear ' This is the web service which of course will exist on the other node as well '
        clearCacheProxy.Url = strService

        AddHandler clearCacheProxy.ClearItemCompleted, AddressOf DoneCallBack

        clearCacheProxy.ClearItemAsync(strPrefix, strPostfix)

    End Sub

    Public Sub DoneCallBack(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CacheClearService.ClearItemCompletedEventArgs)

        ActiveWebServiceCounter -= 1

        If e.Result.Length > 0 Then ' Something failed '
            ' Log the error '
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

The web service on the remote server then calls the same code that the _ClearItem called.

Answer (score 5):

Why not define a Cache Dependancy on an object both servers can see? You could use a [SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) or [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx) cache dependancy.

[Link to Caching Msdn Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx)