# Is it possible to manipulate an asp.net web application cache from outside the web?

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I have a situation very similar to the one in this question:

[Selective Cache clearing across load balanced servers (ASP.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774695/selective-cache-clearing-across-load-balanced-servers-asp-net)

The difference is that due to our hosting configuration, I am unable to address individual servers by IP address. Assuming I cannot access specific servers via web requests, is it possible to access the HttpContext of a web application running on the same machine? I'm thinking I could accomplish this with a windows service that I could address by machine name, or alternately a console application, I just don't know if I can gain access to the web application cache either way.

Comment: Just to see that I understand correctly - you want to access an existing cache running on a website from outside the website?

Comment: Right- I have access to the specific servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose content of the WebCache of an app through some Remoting/WCF code built into the web app. I hope you can use localhost to access it from an app on the same box.

Comment: I think that I can use localhost and set up a an application that shares the same app pool as the root level website.